# Magento 2.3.XX unable to serialize value. error: malformed utf-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Tags: magento2

How can this be solved after upgrading magento 2.2.X to 2.3.X :
[image]

Comment: Try refreshing Redis Cache.

Comment: yes i have done this but it didn't work even

Comment: After running which command you are getting this error

Comment: after upgrading magento 2.2.X to 2.3.X and i have deployed all magento command.

Comment: try to run    rm -rf pub/static/frontend and then check and let me know

Comment: i have also tried this way.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Go to this file location and paste below code and best way try to override this file : **vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php**

```
public function utf8ize( $mixed ) {
    if (is_array($mixed)) foreach ($mixed as $key => $value) $mixed[$key] = $this->utf8ize($value);
    elseif (is_string($mixed)) return mb_convert_encoding($mixed, "UTF-8", "UTF-8");
    return $mixed;
}

public function serialize($data){
    $result = json_encode( $this->utf8ize( $data ) );
    if (false === $result) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Unable to serialize value. Error: " . json_last_error_msg());
    }
    return $result;
}
```

### How to override this file

*The preference for the SerializerInterface was added since 2.2.x version of the Magento, and declared in the `app/etc/di.xml`:*

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Serialize\Json" type="Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json" />
```

> Override Hint :

> Then create the class [Vendor][Module]\Serialize\Serializer\Json that
> extends Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json and make your
> changes in there.

Comment: This solved my issue also on Arabic site.

Answer (score 5):

The below code is working for me after upgrade 2.3.0 to 2.4.2 it will be help

Create di.xml in app/etc/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json" type="Vendor\Module\Serialize\Serializer\Json" />
</config>
```

Create Json.php file in app/etc/code/Vendor/Module/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Serialize\Serializer;

class Json extends \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json
{
    public function serialize($data){
        $result = json_encode( $this->utf8ize( $data ) );
        if (false === $result) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Unable to serialize value. Error: " . json_last_error_msg());
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function unserialize($string)
    {
        $result = json_decode($string, true);
        if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
            if(false !== @unserialize($string)){
                return unserialize($string);
            }
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function utf8ize( $mixed ) {
        if (is_array($mixed)) foreach ($mixed as $key => $value) $mixed[$key] = $this->utf8ize($value);
        elseif (is_string($mixed)) return mb_convert_encoding($mixed, "UTF-8", "UTF-8");
        return $mixed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 checkout cart showing unable to unserialize value. Error syntax error for that error this solution may work.

Go to this path and replace method with below code. **After applying this code please run below command**

**redis-cli flushall**

vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php

```
public function unserialize($string)
    {
        $result = json_decode($string, true);
        if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
            if(false !== @unserialize($string)){
                return unserialize($string);
            }
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

And try to override this file using preference :

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json" type="Namespace\ModuleName\Serialize\Serializer\Json" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this use json_decode function,

```
$response=json_decode ($response,  true,  512,  JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE);
```

Use fourth param is  JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE

Reference: [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
 json_decode(
    string $json,
    ?bool $associative = null,
    int $depth = 512,
    int $flags = 0
): mixed
```

> flags :
> Bitmask of JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE, **JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE**, JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY,
> JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR. The behaviour of these constants is described on
> the JSON constants page.

Hope it will helps.