# Something went wrong while saving the category

Tags: category, magento2.3.5-p1, serializer

I get an error on Magento 2.3.5-p1 when trying to add products to an existing category.
The products won't save and I get this message:

> Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\FileInfo::removeStorePath() must be of the type string, array given, called in /cache/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/FileInfo.php on line 167

If I navigate to the product page to add to a category i get this error:

> Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error

and this in the log:

> [2020-09-18 19:44:02] main.CRITICAL: Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error at /cache/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php:39)"} []

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please share your code as well

Comment: Check you've updated your 3rd party modules. They could be using the php seralize methods instead of using jsons and json encode. That was a change from 2.3.4 to 2.3.5-*

Comment: I just upgrade to 2.4 and disable all third party extension and the issue is still there. My code is the basic magento codes for these pages.

Comment: Try to go to vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/FileInfo.php and debug line 167, "$filePath = $this->removeStorePath($fileName);", check what you're sending in that $fileName, might help getting an hint on what's going on

Answer (score 0):

1. This issue can be caused because of improper file permission ( generate ).
2. If you are using redis try to flush it - redis-cli flushall
3. Problem with your cache - Flush it and then try
4. the last one make changes in Json.php ( Please first try the three above )

// Change unserialize function with this one

```
public function unserialize($string){
    if($this->is_serialized($string)){
        $string = $this->serialize($string);
    }
    $result = json_decode($string, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');
    }
    return $result;
}
```

// Add this on before it

```
function is_serialized($value, &$result = null)
{
    // Bit of a give away this one
    if (!is_string($value))
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Serialized false, return true. unserialize() returns false on an
    // invalid string or it could return false if the string is serialized
    // false, eliminate that possibility.
    if ($value === 'b:0;')
    {
        $result = false;
        return true;
    }
    $length = strlen($value);
    $end    = '';
    switch ($value[0])
    {
        case 's':
            if ($value[$length - 2] !== '"')
            {
                return false;
            }
        case 'b':
        case 'i':
        case 'd':
            // This looks odd but it is quicker than isset()ing
            $end .= ';';
        case 'a':
        case 'O':
            $end .= '}';
            if ($value[1] !== ':')
            {
                return false;
            }
            switch ($value[2])
            {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                case 5:
                case 6:
                case 7:
                case 8:
                case 9:
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        case 'N':
            $end .= ';';
            if ($value[$length - 1] !== $end[0])
            {
                return false;
            }
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    if (($result = @unserialize($value)) === false)
    {
        $result = null;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Find More info in this page
[Magento 2.2: Unable to unserialize value?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194010/magento-2-2-unable-to-unserialize-value)

Answer (score 0):

I think the below code will help you to fix the serialization error.

```
namespace M2\Mage24Fix\Framework\Serialize\Serializer;

/**
 * Class Title
 * 
 * Fix fatal with serialize json for 2.4.0 version - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/286634/magento-2-3-xx-unable-to-serialize-value-error-malformed-utf-8-characters-pos
 */
class Json extends \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     * @since 101.0.0   
     */
    public function serialize($data)
    {
        try{
            $result = json_encode($data);
            if (false === $result) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Unable to serialize value. Error: " . json_last_error_msg());
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e){
            $result = json_encode( $this->utf8ize( $data ) );
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     * @since 101.0.0
     */
    public function utf8ize( $mixed ) {
        if (is_array($mixed)) foreach ($mixed as $key => $value) $mixed[$key] = $this->utf8ize($value);
        elseif (is_string($mixed)) return mb_convert_encoding($mixed, "UTF-8", "UTF-8");
        return $mixed;
    }
}
```

Please override this file in app/code/M2 custom module.
PHP bin/magento setup:upgrade
PHP bin/magento cache:flush

Please let me know if this will not work.
Thahks.

Answer (score 0):

Emili,

I checked the Magento 2.3.5-p1 code base,

The exception is thrown by an attribute that Backend model instance of **Image**.

[image: Backend model]

=>

- Please review your EAV attributes (eav_attribute) which have backend model like `'%image%'`,
- Check the before load, before save, after load, after save, makes sure the attribute's value afterload isn't instance of an array.