# There has been an error processing your request: "0":"Unable to serialize value. Error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded"

Tags: magento2, error, plugin, file-permissions, interceptor

I am attempting to set up my local environment for Magento. When I try to view the front end, I get the following error on the page:

```
There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 4982d0e3c31863370d845d5635c2d16b81705475bfaa31edbd462354d0f17305
```

The log states the following:

```
{"0":"Unable to serialize value. Error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded","1":"#1 Magento\\Framework\\App\\PageCache\\Kernel->process() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/Controller\/Result\/BuiltinPlugin.php:96]\n#2 Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\Controller\\Result\\BuiltinPlugin->afterRenderResult() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:146]\n#3 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#4 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Result\/Page\/Interceptor.php:130]\n#5 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->renderResult() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:120]\n#6 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php:24]\n#7 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:261]\n#8 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub\/index.php:40]\n","url":"\/","script_name":"\/index.php","report_id":"4982d0e3c31863370d845d5635c2d16b81705475bfaa31edbd462354d0f17305"}
```

I have attempted to compile and reindex with no luck. I am fairly certain file permissions have been set up correctly, as I [used the docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/before/before-setup-env-install.html) to set them up with these commands:

```
cd <magento_root>
sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f   -exec chmod g+w {} +
sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d   -exec chmod g+ws {} +
sudo chown -R :<web server group> .
sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated. I am new to Magento, so please tell me if I need to provide any more information.

Comment: check this link :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/286664/85907

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are saving the data in your database that is not supported by database like (special symbols) etc

use like this `$data = utf8_encode($row[14]);` to convert and then save it

If help kindly accept and up-vote

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: i mean to say you need to convert the value in to this format before saving it